# Concatenate values for matching items in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have more than a thousand rows of data like this:

[image: data]

I need to concatenate the values into comma delimited strings for matching items in the list.  So, for example, the result for Item 1 would look like this:

[image: result]

I tried a couple of concatenate + IF, but my logic is not working.  I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a straightforward way to do it that doesn't require anything fancy.  First, sort the data on Column A so that the similar items are together.

Add two columns:

[image: step 1]

The new Name column is where the string gets built and the Flag column identifies the last row for each item.  The formula in C2 is:

```
 =IF(A2=A1,C1&","&B2,B2)
```

Copy this down the column.  If the row contains the first entry for the item, it uses the column B value to start the string.  If it is a subsequent row, it concatenates a comma to the previous column C value and then adds the current column B value to it.

Cell D2 contains:

```
=IF(A3=A2,"",1)
```

Copy that down the column.  If the next row contains the same item, column D is left blank.  If the next row is a new item, that means this is the last row for the current item and column D gets a `1`.

The next step is to use a filter, set to Flag = 1, to hide all rows for which Column D is not `1`.

[image: step 2]

Then hide columns B and D.  That gives you this:

[image: step 3]